# Whats wrong ? Simple heuristic to calculate current moon phase from a date

Tags: python

**Current Moon phase:**
I was searching for a simple way to compute the current Moon phase, and all the answers are way too complicated.

So I wrote this simple program, but it's so simple in comparison, is there something wrong ?

With a ±19 hour variation in Moon phases I know it can be out by about a day.

**PS.** I'm quite new to Python. **PPS.** I see now i mispelt 'modulos'

```
from datetime import datetime

baseline_new_moon = datetime(2022, 2, 1)    # A new moon at 00:46am
now = datetime.now()
difference = float((now - baseline_new_moon).days) - 0.0319     # Days difference as a float
                                                                # subtract 46 mins ~3.19% of a day
modulos = difference % 29.53    # Subtract all full moon cycles, (29.53 days, Wikipedia)
                                # remainder is current mooncycle phase progress

moonphase = ""

if (modulos < 1.84 or modulos >= 27.68 ):   # This is the only real one that needs to be 
    moonphase = "new moon"                  # precise. 0 is centre of new Moon phase  
                                            # Each is 29.53 / 8 (the 8 phases)

elif (modulos >= 1.84 and modulos < 5.53):
    moonphase = "cresent (right)"

elif (modulos >= 5.53 and modulos < 9.22):
    moonphase = "half moon (right)"

elif (modulos >= 9.22 and modulos < 12.91):
    moonphase = "3/4 moon (right)"

elif (modulos >= 12.91 and modulos < 16.61):
    moonphase = "full moon"

elif (modulos >= 16.61 and modulos < 20.30):
    moonphase = "3/4 moon (left)"

elif (modulos >= 20.30 and modulos < 23.99):
    moonphase = "half moon (left)"

elif (modulos >= 23.99 and modulos < 27.68):
    moonphase = "cresent (left)"

print(moonphase)
```

Comment: Hello, what is the result you expect ?

Comment: Just a simple way to calculate moon phases with today's date with a ±19 hour variation. If someone searches for the same and there's nothing wrong with this -it is much simpler than the other programs that show in the search.

Comment: maybe you should calculate for different years (especially `leap years`) and compare with results from other programs/modules - this way you will see if you get correct results.

Comment: yes, I like the comparison idea. I don't think the leap years will matter much, datetime must be a pretty reliable library and the program simply subtracts one date from another using the library.